# How to fix "Section .vectors overlaps section .data " | Adding ATmega1281 Support to Compiler

Tags: cross-compiling, libc, atmega, avr-gcc, gcc3

So, I was working on a project to add ATmega1281 architecture support to my Toolchain.

I was having `avr-gcc-v3.3`, `avr-binutils-2.13.1`, and `avr-libc-cvs2003.`

I have added the ATmega1281 support to `Binutils-2.13`, `Gcc-3.3` and `Avr-libc-cvs2003`.

After the complete toolchain is created, when I try to compile a Hello-World program for the ATmega1281, I get the following errors.

[Error Given when executed with -mmcu=atmega1281](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsDVk.png)

I tried with other mcu's , they are working fine except the ATmega1281.

**What can be the issue here ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know but the issue was with something related to the autoconf, automake and texinfo.

i downgraded it and it works fine.